# Git pull on a dev branch by mistake and get " This branch is 2 commits ahead, 13 commits behind master. "

Tags: git

## What I want to do

**I just would like to solve this message**

```
This branch is 2 commits ahead, 13 commits behind master.
```

## Why it happened

I did `git pull` on my develop branch by mistake. Apparently, I did `git commit -m` a couple of times after I did that. That's why I'm getting this message.

## Detail

I found several solutions about my problem but I cannot tell from which is a right solution to me. I am not familiar with `git` so I cannot understand **what doing `git pull` on a develop branch caused to my repository**.

If it is alright with you, I would like you to tell me how to solve this problem and what is going on my repository.

Thank you very much.

This is the result of my `git reflog`

```
25a9c24 (HEAD -> develop, origin/develop) HEAD@{0}: commit: [Add] 進行中の取引一覧ページ追加 #150
1c15093 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from master to develop
ad6582f (origin/master, master) HEAD@{2}: pull: Fast-forward
0b4d412 HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from develop to master
1c15093 HEAD@{4}: commit: [Fix] Request_Deal_TableをDealにも対応できるよう更新
2a0e143 HEAD@{5}: commit: [Update]申請されたリクエスト一覧ページ完成 #149
aabb0e8 HEAD@{6}: commit: [Update] Request_Waitingに画面遷移機能追加
2f82622 HEAD@{7}: checkout: moving from master to develop
0b4d412 HEAD@{8}: pull: Fast-forward
aa9e763 HEAD@{9}: checkout: moving from develop to master
2f82622 HEAD@{10}: commit: [Update] Request_Detail完成 #143
baa5d3f HEAD@{11}: checkout: moving from master to develop
aa9e763 HEAD@{12}: pull: Fast-forward
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In git, you normally have one local and one remote version of each branch stored in your machine. In your case, your remote is named `origin` and you have the branches `master` and `origin/master`, `develop` and `origin/develop`. The remote version of your branches is bound to a url where that branch can synchronize its states.
You can see your remote informations using the command: `git remote -v`

When you do `git checkout develop` and than `git pull`, git does the following:

- brings all the new commits from develop branch on remote url to the `origin/develop` branch in your machine
- merges the `origin/develop` branch to `develop` branch

The message bellow means your current branch has two commits that are not present in `master` branch and `master` branch has 13 commits your current branch doesn't have.

```
This branch is 2 commits ahead, 13 commits behind master.
```

If you want to make your `develop` branch have all `master` branch commits you merge master into your develop by running `git merge master`.

To better understand the git branches I recommend to use visual tools like gitk.

The command `gitk --all` will display the state of all your branches:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your great explanation. I understand what situation I am in now. However, I still don't find how I can solve this issue.

Comment: I updated the answer adding the following. Check if it is what you need: "If you want to make your `develop` branch have all `master` branch commits you merge master into your develop by running `git merge master`."

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I figured it out in another way but this is a new good way. It's good study to me. Thank you very much again.